# Server doesn't recive my POST request from android

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection

I'm sending a POST request to my server, just in order to check if my connection works, but it isn't reciving any data from my app. I've tried everything, and these are my conclusions: 1. The query is generated in a proper way (I've printed it and looks nice). 2. The code doesn't throw any error. 3. The code runs till the end.

Here is my code:

```
 public static void addLocation(final Location location, final String title, final String author, final String text, final boolean anonymous){
    Thread nt = new Thread(){
        @Override
    public void run(){
            try{

                Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

                String slocation = location.getLatitude()+"@"+location.getLongitude();
                String sanonymous;
                if(anonymous){
                    sanonymous = "true";
                }else{
                    sanonymous = "false";
                }

                parameters.put("location", slocation);
                parameters.put("author", author);
                parameters.put("title", title);
                parameters.put("text", text);
                parameters.put("anonymous", sanonymous);


                URL urlToRequest = new URL("http://mashiron.xyz/_03z/pia/proc.php");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection =
                        (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


                String postParameters = createQueryStringForParameters(parameters);

                urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(
                        postParameters.getBytes().length);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

               // System.out.println(receiveResponse(urlConnection));
                out.close();
                System.out.println("1# "+postParameters);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("2");

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
    nt.start();
}
```

This is the util I'm using in order to generate my query from the hashmap, but as I said, I think the problem isn't there.

```
public static String createQueryStringForParameters(Map<String, String> parameters) {
    StringBuilder parametersAsQueryString = new StringBuilder();
    if (parameters != null) {
        boolean firstParameter = true;

        for (String parameterName : parameters.keySet()) {
            if (!firstParameter) {
                parametersAsQueryString.append(PARAMETER_DELIMITER);
            }

            parametersAsQueryString.append(parameterName)
                    .append(PARAMETER_EQUALS_CHAR)
                    .append(URLEncoder.encode(
                            parameters.get(parameterName)));

            firstParameter = false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("4");

    return parametersAsQueryString.toString();
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have done it all right but you forgot to write your content to the `OutputStream`. Add this Line after opening the `out` stream

```
out.write(postParameters);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ahmed, but I still doesn't work. As you said, I added that line to my code:                     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                    out.write(postParameters); But it doesn't work.

Comment: Btw, I forgot to say I'm getting this error in the console: W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

Comment: Were you how did send this request to the server? {"gmm":{"c":{"code":"200","time":"1458169980"},"r":{"status":"OK","raw":{"anonymous":"true","author":"2323","text":"eefe","title":"232","location":"sdds"},"rf_us":null}}}

Comment: You can get the response code and check if you can get any response codes then you are connected `int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode(); System.out.println(responseCode);`

Comment: This is a Json request. The one you constructed is not a Json. It's like this `anonymous=true&author=2323&text=eefe&title=232&location=sdds`

Comment: I checked the code with my adition and it's working. You just need to format your request in a proper way. I'm getting 200 response code = YOU ARE CONNECTED!

Comment: I sent my request with the parameters in the format you suggested: "anonymous=true&author=2323&text=eefe&title=232&location=sdds" (so: String postParameters = "anonymous=true&author=2323&text=eefe&title=232&location=sdds";) and I recived the code 200, but this exception as well: W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected. The server is reciving the code 400. Thanks once again.

Comment: If you have 200 then you got connected. and I didn't suggest tjis format. I don't know how the server is expecting your request but you say in apreious comment that it's a Json not just  normal text.

Comment: Ahmed, may you post the full class you used to send the test string? So far, it has been the only one which we hace recived. We tried to send the same but as I said, he got the 400 error. Yours has been de only one which worked. Thanks!